# Artifacts deployment on nexus repositories manager

Tags: spring

Im receiving this when I attempt to login to https://oss.sonatype.org/

Im using the same credentials as for https://issues.sonatype.org/

Im also receiving the same problem while trying to publish artifacts 'Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized'

Could you please help me to avoid this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit? How exactly are you trying to log in? How is that related to `spring`. `HTTP` 401 means there was no auth info in general.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: good  @VladimirPligin but please leave me your contact i want to talk to you privately! because i realized you are familiar with those stuffs. please give me your email of text me here : valensniyonsenga2003@gmaill.com